# Echo decimal value without point zero ( .0 ) at end

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using

> Decimal (5,1)

to store my data.
When value is `12.2, 66.4`... evething is ok.
But the NOT decimal value : `5, 10 , 20` .... when echo will be `5.0, 10.0` ...

**How can I echo them look like :**

```
1, 2.2, 2.5, 10, 10.5, 10.6, 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon Linoff's answer may do the trick, but here is the PHP way to do so :

```
echo (intval($var) == $var) ? intval($var) : $var;
```

Or, if you don't like ternary conditions :

```
if (intval($var) == $var) {
    echo intval($var);
} else {
    echo $var;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I use this solution with my page. Look like everythings is ok.

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful. If you think this solution is the one that solved the problem, please click the green tick so other users can see it too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the value and decide how to format it.  The type specification says "keep one digit after the decimal place", and MySQL diligently does that.

There are lots of ways.  Here is one:

```
select (case when val = cast(val as int) then format(val, 0)
        else format(val, 10) end)
```

Format adds commas, which (to me) seems desirable for numbers greater than 1,000.  But there are other methods if you don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution working for any number of fractional digits:
remove all trailing zeroes and if the last character is a period, remove it too:

```
TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM (TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM (CAST(col AS VARCHAR(40))))))
```

Comment: I tried cast in my SQL query but dont know how it can't be processed. I think my CSM have some troubles with this method.